# How does qsort work?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Can someone explain what this sort algorithm does? I can't follow the logic, and it uses recursion. It seems strange to take the middle term and swap it with the first (8th line from top). Also, in the first iteration, `++last = i`, so the call to swap is wasted.

The code sets `last = left`, `i = left + 1`, and then calls swap() with `++last`. This makes `last` equal `i`!

```
/* qsort: sort v[left]...v[right] into increasing order */
void qsort(int v[], int left, int right)
{
    int i, last;

    if (left >= right) /* do nothing if array contains */
        return; /* fewer than two elements */

    swap(v, left, (left + right)/2); /* move partition elem */
    last = left;                     /* to v[0] */

    for (i = left + 1; i <= right; i++) /* partition */
        if (v[i] < v[left])
            swap(v, ++last, i);
    swap(v, left, last); /* restore partition elem */
    qsort(v, left, last-1);
    qsort(v, last+1, right);
}

/* swap: interchange v[i] and v[j] */
void swap(int v[], int i, int j)
{
    int temp;
    temp = v[i];
    v[i] = v[j];
    v[j] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Read the chapter on quick sort in the book Introduction to Algorithms by CLRS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments in code are quite explaining. At the beginning, a 'partition' element is selected and moved to the beginning of the array so that the subsequent swaps don't touch it. Then all remaining elements are partially sorted so this 'partition' element can be inserted into its final place in the sorted array, and this is what the last swap does (just before calling recursion for the parts to the left and to the right to the partition element).

For the algorithm's details, read about [Quick sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).